# downloads the content at the specified URL

Tags: c#

I want to download only contents from websites. What is the best approach for that? I have tried   `WebClient` but using that I am getting all the tags also. I just want contents..

Following is my code :

```
 WebClient w = new WebClient();

//Using DownloadString
 string s = w.DownloadString("http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Main_Page");
 Console.WriteLine(s);

//Using DownloadData
 byte[] downloadedData = w.DownloadData("http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Main_Page");
 string data = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(downloadedData);
 Console.WriteLine(data);
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: what you really want is a scrapper?

Comment: Use a DOM parser.  Something like the HTMLAgilityPack perhaps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose you want to strip the the downloaded html and parse the contents of a url ?

For such purposes i have a static class (found on stackoverflow):

```
public static class StringExtensions
{
    public static string StripHTML(this string htmlString)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(htmlString)) return htmlString;

        string pattern = @"<(.|\n)*?>";

        string s = Regex.Replace(htmlString, pattern, string.Empty);

        return s;
    }
}
```

And you can use it like that:

```
string s = SomeDownloadFunction("http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Main_Page");
string content = s.StripHTML();
```

Answer (score 0):

While removing the tags can be easily achieved with RegEx, if what you want is to retrieve all the actual content on the page (ignoring advertisements, navigation bars, etc), that is a really hard task. Fortunately, some very smart people are nice enough to share their researches in this area. Have a look at [boilerpipe](https://code.google.com/p/boilerpipe/) (demo [here](http://boilerpipe-web.appspot.com)).